# Using hashcode for a unique ID

Tags: java, unique, hashcode

I am working in a java-based system where I need to set an id for certain elements in the visual display. One category of elements is Strings, so I decided to use the String.hashCode() method to get a unique identifier for these elements.

The problem I ran into, however, is that the system I am working in borks if the id is negative and `String.hashCode` often returns negative values. One quick solution is to just use Math.abs() around the hashcode call to guarantee a positive result. What I was wondering about this approach is what are the chances of two distinct elements having the same hashcode?

For example, if one string returns a hashcode of -10 and another string returns a hashcode of 10 an error would occur. In my system we're talking about collections of objects that aren't more than 30 elements large typically so I don't think this would really be an issue, but I am curious as to what the math says.

Comment: If you can be sure of some small upper limit of how many objects you have, you can check for a collision each time you calculate an id. If you find one, you could add 1 until you got a unique value, for instance, being careful of integer overflow. Or just make the ids 1,2,3, ...

Comment: There is no `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` as `-MIN_VALUE == MIN_VALUE == 0x8000_0000`. Use `hc & Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead if you remain with your strategy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hash codes can be thought of as pseudo-random numbers. Statistically, with a positive `int` hash code the chance of a collision between any two elements reaches 50% when the population size is about 54K (and 77K for *any* `int`). See [Birthday Problem Probability Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table) for collision probabilities of various hash code sizes.

Also, your idea to use `Math.abs()` alone is flawed: It does not always return a positive number! In 2's compliment arithmetic, the absolute value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is itself!  Famously, the hash code of `"polygenelubricants"` is this value.

Answer (score 8):

Hashes are not unique, hence they are not appropriate for **uniqueId**.

As to probability of hash collision, you could read about [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). Actually (from what I recall) when drawing from an uniform distribution of N values, you should expect collision after drawing `$\sqrt(N)$` (you could get collision much earlier). The problem is that Java's implementation of `hashCode` (and especially when hashing short strings) doesn't provide uniform distribution, so you'll get collision much earlier.

Comment: Interesting. Like I said, my data sets shouldn't get bigger than 30-50 values (and this would be for a system that would not scale) so I guess I would be safe here.

Comment: Yes. But for a system with 30-50 values any other scheme would also work... and most would be safer. If you don't plan to have more than 50 values just assingn unique id's by hand.

Answer (score 3):

You already can get two strings with the same hashcode. This should be obvious if you think that you have an infinite number of strings and only 2^32 possible hashcodes.

You just make it a little more probable when taking the absolute value. The risk is small but if you **need** an unique id, this isn't the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do when you only have 30-50 values as you said is register each String you get into an HashMap together with a running counter as value:

```
HashMap StringMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

StringMap.add("Test",1);
StringMap.add("AnotherTest",2);
```

You can then get your unique ID by calling this:

```
StringMap.get("Test"); //returns 1
```