# Android, custom adapter, string and long id

Tags: java, android, json, string

i was coding an app for Android but i got stuck in this problem.
Basically the app shows a list of movie, then tapping on a movie opens an activity containing the details of the movie, including trailers.
I'm using the API given from www.themoviedb.org.
I coded a custom adapter in order to show the trailers and infos about them (language, site, title) into a listview displayed in the DetailActivity.
Here's my problem:
for example the json response for trailers is this:

```
{"id":135397,"results":[{"id":"54749bea9251414f41001b58","iso_639_1":"en","key":"bvu-zlR5A8Q","name":"Teaser","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Teaser"},{"id":"5474d2339251416e58002ae1","iso_639_1":"en","key":"RFinNxS5KN4","name":"Official Trailer","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"},{"id":"56404e639251417052000369","iso_639_1":"en","key":"aJJrkyHas78","name":"Official Global Trailer","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"}]}
```

The problem is: when i override the `getItemId` method of `BaseAdapter` i have to return a `long` value, but i can't manage to convert the `id` from the json 
 (for example the string `54749bea9251414f41001b58`) to `long`.
It looks like an hexadecimal but it's way too large.
So far i tried:

- getting the value with `getString` method of `jsonObject`
- getting the value as String and using `Long.parse(String x)` method
- getting the value as String and using `Long.parse(String x, int radix)`  method, passing 16 as radix

In all of the cases above the result was always the same, this Exception:
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "54749bea9251414f41001b58"`

Is there any way to extract a valid id from this evil string? Or to "force" `BaseAdapter` to return a `String` instead of a `long` from the `getItemId` method?

Thanks in advance. I omitted the code of all java classes because i don't think is necessary, i can add it if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the position from your getItemId() method like

```
long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
}
```

Or if you have created a POJO then you can do like this one

```
    long getItemId(int position) {
      return yourItem.hashCode();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! the first one worked, how could i not think that!
By the way, can i ask you what a POJO is? I mean, could i have used the second one in this case with no problem or should i do some extra work?

Comment: POJO stands for Plain Old Java Object. Its like creating a Java class with properties or attributes like id, iso, key and name with setter and getter methods. The object of this class will represent a movie entity.

Comment: Oh yeah it is. Well now it's all clear thank you sir!

Comment: Second advice is wrong, hashCode should NOT be used as unique identifier of the item! See for example :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368492/using-hashcode-for-a-unique-id