# how to get only positive results when applying hashCode()?

Tags: scala, range, hashcode

I am working on a Scala code that convert set of unique strings to unique IDs. I applied HashCode() but I got negative numbers and I need to work only with positive numbers. 
I know that I have to use math.abs to get rid of the negative values but I am not sure if this is the correct solution or not. 
If I read before that something like this could solve my problem

```
math.abs(hashCode()) * constant % size
```

how can I determine the right constant? and does the size means the total number of strings?

previous questions related to that topic solved the question by using math.abs only but if the total number of string is large an overflow could happen and there is a chance to get a negative number as well. by multiplying the result with constant and take the mod of size could help. This is why I need to understand how to determine the constant and the size?

Also is there another way to get unique numbers for unique strings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using hashcode for a unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368492/using-hashcode-for-a-unique-id)

Comment: I did not get an answer for my question from the mentioned post.

Comment: Why not it says `your idea to use Math.abs() alone is flawed: It does not always return a positive number!` and it also explains hash code is not unique.

Comment: I would like to understand how to apply the formula mentioned in my question to improve the uniqueness of the result

Comment: using multiplication and mod could help me

Comment: @saad multiplication and mod will not help with uniqueness. However, I tried to generalize your question and gave a possible solution.

Comment: @saad you might want to update the question title with the general form.

Answer (score 0):

We can phrase your problem another way: **How to get an unsigned number from a signed number with the same range?**

Suppose you are using an Integer. Its value goes from -2147483648 to 2147483647. Now you need to convert this value into the positive range 0 to 2147483647.

---

**Step 1:**
ADD a constant to move the range upwards to 0. You can do this by adding 2147483648 to the value. But now the highest possible value is much greater than the MAX.

**Step 2:**
So use MODULO to move the value back into the required range.

---

For example, consider the values -2000 and 2000000000.

```
| STEP              | MIN VALUE  | EXAMPLE 1  | EXAMPLE 2  | MAX VALUE  |
|-------------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| original          |-2147483648 |   -2000    | 2000000000 | 2147483647 |
| add 2147483648    |     0      | 2147481648 | 4147483648 | 4294967295 |
| modulo 2147483648 |     0      | 2147481648 | 2000000001 | 2147483647 |
```

So the final formula is:

```
(NUMBER + 2147483648) % 2147481648
```

---

> **Warning:**
>   Hash codes are not designed to give unique values. There are chances of  getting the same hash for two different strings. Also, any scaling operations on the hash (like division, modulo) can further reduce uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

To strip a sign from an `Int`, you can just use `.abs`. It does break on `Int.MinValue`, but you can just special case it:

```
def stripSign(n: Int) = math.abs(n) max 0
```

or simply drop the sign bit:

```
def stripSign2(n: Int) = n & Int.MaxValue
```

Or just use negative numbers (what's wrong with them anyway?).

To your other question, you cannot convert a bunch of unique strings to ints, and guarantee that there won't be duplications (for the simple reason that there are *more* strings than distinct `Int`s, so, if you wanted to assign an unique int to each of them, you'd run out of ints before you run out of strings), so you have to be able to handle collisions, however infrequent.

You can only shoot for lowering the probability of a collision by making your hash longer (with a 32-bit hash code, you have about 50% probability of at least one collision in a population of approximately 75000 strings, with 31 bits (if you do not want negative numbers), it is 55000, but with a 64-bit hash, the "magic number" is about 5 *billion*, provided that your hash function is good enough, and produces the numbers that are very evenly distributed).